# Zoom sdk self is not defined - nextjs, react

Tags: reactjs, github, next.js, zoom-sdk

Next js, trying to use zoom sdk

ReferenceError: self is not defined

I am getting ReferenceError: self is not defined while trying to integrate zoom sdk in next js. Here is my code.
I am getting ReferenceError: self is not defined while trying to integrate zoom sdk in next js. Here is my code.
I am getting ReferenceError: self is not defined while trying to integrate zoom sdk in next js. Here is my code.
I am getting ReferenceError: self is not defined while trying to integrate zoom sdk in next js. Here is my code.

This is my component - the same with doc’s example:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqyPA.png)

```
import { ZoomMtg } from ‘@zoomus/websdk’;

ZoomMtg.setZoomJSLib(‘https://source.zoom.us/2.14.0/lib’, ‘/av’);

ZoomMtg.preLoadWasm();
ZoomMtg.prepareWebSDK();

function App() {
var authEndpoint = ‘’;
var sdkKey = ‘’;
var meetingNumber = ‘123456789’;
var passWord = ‘’;
var role = 0;
var userName = ‘React’;
var userEmail = ‘’;
var registrantToken = ‘’;
var zakToken = ‘’;
var leaveUrl = ‘http://localhost:3000’;

function getSignature(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch(authEndpoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            meetingNumber: meetingNumber,
            role: role,
        }),
    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((response) => {
            startMeeting(response.signature);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}

function startMeeting(signature) {
    document.getElementById('zmmtg-root').style.display = 'block';

    ZoomMtg.init({
        leaveUrl: leaveUrl,
        success: (success) => {
            console.log(success);

            ZoomMtg.join({
                signature: signature,
                sdkKey: sdkKey,
                meetingNumber: meetingNumber,
                passWord: passWord,
                userName: userName,
                userEmail: userEmail,
                tk: registrantToken,
                zak: zakToken,
                success: (success) => {
                    console.log(success);
                },
                error: (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                },
            });
        },
        error: (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        },
    });
}

return (
        <main>
            <h1>Zoom Meeting SDK Sample React</h1>

            <button onClick={getSignature}>Join Meeting</button>
        </main>
);
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

server side import problem

probably the reason is that it should be placed in useEffect. This is how it works for me

```
import MeetingStyles from '../styles/zoom.module.scss';

const Meeting = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    return async () => {
      new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const ZoomEmbed = await (
          await import('@zoomus/websdk/embedded')
        ).default;

        let client = ZoomEmbed.createClient();

        client.init({
          language: 'en-US',
          zoomAppRoot: meetingSDKElement,
        });

        let payload = router.query;

        const { data } = await axios({
          url: 'api/zoom',
          method: 'post',
          data: payload,
        })
          .then((response) => {
            return response;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log('----signature axios request error====>', error);
          });

        client.join({
          meetingNumber: payload.meetingNumber,
          signature: data.signature,
          sdkKey: data.sdkKey,
          userName: payload.userName,
          password: payload.password,
          tk: '',
        });
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('---- Error inside useEffect -->', error);
      });
    };
  });

  return (
    <div className={MeetingStyles.container}>
      <div
        className={MeetingStyles.meetingSDKElement}
        id="meetingSDKElement"
      ></div>
      <div className={MeetingStyles.content}>Content</div>
    </div>
  );
};

Meeting.displayName = 'Zoom component View';

export default Meeting;
```

api looks like this

```
    const KJUR = require('jsrsasign');


export default function handler(req, res) {
  const iat = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) - 30;
  const exp = iat + 60 * 60 * 2;

  const oHeader = { alg: 'HS256', typ: 'JWT' };

  const oPayload = {
    sdkKey: 'your Client ID',
    mn: req.body.meetingNumber,
    role: req.body.role,
    iat: iat,
    exp: exp,
    appKey: 'your Client ID',
    tokenExp: iat + 60 * 60 * 2,
  };

  const sHeader = JSON.stringify(oHeader);
  const sPayload = JSON.stringify(oPayload);
  const signature = KJUR.KJUR.jws.JWS.sign(
    'HS256',
    sHeader,
    sPayload,
    'your Client Secret'
  );

  return res.json({
    signature: signature,
    sdkKey: 'your Client ID',
  });
}
```

accordingly, the address will be as follows:

```
http://localhost:3000/zoom?meetingNumber=yourMeetingNumber&role=0&userName=yourName&password=11111
```

Comment: Please translate this into English